# java tomcat a3 certificate

Tags: java, tomcat, x509certificate

How to configure TOMCAT to make the browser show the installed certificates (A3; token USB) when a URL (servlet) is called?

I will retriev the X509 certificate on the servlet request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand, but I'm guessing that you want tomcat to request a certificate from a client.

If this is the case, then you will want to enable what is called mutual authentication in tomcat.

You will have to set the clientAuth attribute of your tomcat ssl connector to either want or true.  The ssl connector will be found in your tomcat server.xml file.

'want' asks the client to send a certificate if it has one, but the request will go though if the client doesn't have a certificate and 'true' means the client is required to send a certificate and the request will fail if the client does not provide a certificate.

More information can be found on the tomcat website:
[SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)